# free() invalid next size (fast) -C++ Memory error

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, memory-management

My program mycpp.c throws memory error,i think this error has been raised due to overwrite the object pointer but i couldn't trace out
root cause of the error.I felt that the line "ref3[1]= ref3[0] +reference;" is causing an issue and i commented it so .but it didn't helped me.could you please help me to resolve the error. 
**mycpp.c**

```
void mycpp::filldata(ptrStructda pStData)
   1871 {
             ../stmt/...

   1947         String s2("");
   1948         strcat(ref3[0],reference);
   1949         strcat(s2,ref3[0]);
   1950            // ref3[1]= ref3[0] +reference;
   1951             s2.replace_char('-','.');
   1952            // Clean and hold the output value
   1953             temp_Buffer->erase();
   1954         *temp_Buffer = "";
   1955         cout<<"S2:\t"<<s2<<endl;
   1956 //      strcpy(*temp_Buffer,s2);
   1957 }
```

**String.c**

```
String::String()
{
        _text = new char[1024];
}

String::String(char *ch)
{
        if (ch == NULL )
        {
                // if input char* is empty - allocate short buffer
                // and set it to ""
                _text = new char[2];
                strcpy(_text, "");
        }
        else
        {   
                _text = new char[strlen(ch) + 1];
                    if(_text)
                         strcpy(_text, ch);
                else
                {
                        _text = new char[2];
                        strcpy(_text, "");
                }
        }

}

String::String(int iLen)
{
        _text = new char[iLen+1];
}
String::String(String const & string)//jl202 added const
{
       _text = new char[string.length() + 1];

       strcpy(_text,string);
}
String::~String()
{
        delete[] _text;
}
String &String::operator=(String &ptrStr)
{

        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[ptrStr.length() + 1];
        strcpy(_text, ptrStr);
        return *this;
}
String &String::operator=(char *ch)
{
        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[strlen(ch) + 1];

        strcpy(_text, ch);
        return *this;
}
void String::erase()
{
        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[1];
}
```

String.h

```
class String
{
    private:
            char *_text;

            friend class String_Iterator;
    public:
            // ctors and dtor
            explicit String ();                     // create String as of 1024 chars
            explicit String (char *);
            explicit String (int );
            String (String const & );               // copy ctor
            ~String();

            /////////////////
            // conversions:
            /////////////////
            //  to C-like type char *
            operator  char *() {return _text;}

            operator const char*()const
            {
               return (const_cast <char *>(_text) );
            }
 };
```

**gdb inputs for observation**

```
(gdb) bt

   #5  0x0000000000402fda in String::~String (this=0x7fffffffd2f0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at String.c:55
**#6  0x000000000040d58c in mycpp::filldata (this=0x61f0e0, pStData=0x7fffffffdd50) at mycpp.c:1955**
#7  0x000000000041159d in mycpp::base (this=0x61f0e0, pStData=0x7fffffffdd50, account_id=0x6418e0 "0300130",
    page_balance=0x7fffffffdf38, items_on_page=0x7fffffffdf34, txn_per_acc=0x7fffffffdf30, total_cash_bal=0x7fffffffdf28, total_cv_bal=0x7fffffffdf20)
    at mycpp.c:1328
#8  0x0000000000414e77 in mycpp::Proc (this=0x61f0e0) at mycpp.c:899
#9  0x000000000041704e in mycpp::Run (this=0x61f060) at mycpp.c:97
#10 0x0000000000417146 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe1f8) at mycpp.c:2264
```

Thanks for looking into this.
Seeking your valuable solution

Comment: Downvoted. This is not a question, nor did it seem like you put a real effort into fixing this yourself. Try simplifying your case until you near it down to a few lines of code.

Comment: Your code is (1) incomplete and (2) still way too much for us to debug for you. A suggestion: Valgrind will give you a better idea of where the problems are than just GDB.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please boil your question and code down such that makes
up for a real technical question. What I already see, is that you are
freelyy mixing C and C++. ".c" files are usually C but you have C++
classes inside. Cleanup your code and your concepts.

Comment: Modified the contents.placed only the piece of code which throws an error and others are removed.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
String s2("");
...
strcat(s2,...);
```

is definitively a bad idea. In the first line, you'll allocate an array of `char` of length 1 and assign it to `s2._text`. And with `strcat`, you try to append characters to `s2._text` but you are not reserving additional characters for it, so you are overwriting (corrupting) memory you should not be writing to (causing unexpected effects in random places of your program), unless of course the second argument of `strcat(..)` is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try `std::string`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues:

Undefined content:

```
String::String()
{
        _text = new char[1024];
        // The content of this array is not defined.
        // It may not contain a null terminator.
        // FIX:
        _text[0] = '\0';
}

String::String(char *ch)
{
        if (ch == NULL )  // Should use `nullptr`
        {
                _text = new char[2];   // Why 2!
                strcpy(_text, "");
        }
        else
        {   
                _text = new char[strlen(ch) + 1];
                    if(_text)                     // new never returns null.
                                                  // So this test is usless.
                                                  // It works or it throws.
                         strcpy(_text, ch);
                else
                {
                        _text = new char[2];     // What would have happened if this failed?
                        strcpy(_text, "");
                }
        }

}

String::String(int iLen)
{
        _text = new char[iLen+1];  // Again not null termianted.
}
String::String(String const & string)//jl202 added const
{
       _text = new char[string.length() + 1];

       strcpy(_text,string);
}
String::~String()
{
        delete[] _text;
}

// Normally you would set the parameter as const reference.
String &String::operator=(String &ptrStr)
{

        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[ptrStr.length() + 1];
        strcpy(_text, ptrStr);
        return *this;
}
String &String::operator=(char *ch)
{
        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[strlen(ch) + 1];

        strcpy(_text, ch);
        return *this;
}
void String::erase()
{
        delete[] _text;
        _text = new char[1]; // This does not initialize the string with a null terminator.
}
```